# Rule engine VS Using Java Custom Constraint Validator

Tags: java, json, hibernate, validation

I am evaluating whether to use a suitable architecture and API such as Java Custom Constraint Validator vs JRules for my project and need quite a expertise help.
http://blog.athico.com/2007/08/jboss-drools-vs-ilog-jrules.html

Business requirement is web form base submission system for clinical system as basic details as below
i) 1000 clinics

ii) Total 20 clinic form types ( registration, patient info, medicine info, drug info, etc)

iii) Each form has approximately 10-30 medium to complex rules ( i.e. identification number cannot be null if visitor age more than 12 years old )

iv) Each form has approximately 40 fields ( name, address, location, etc)

v) Conditions of the rules generally within 3-5

vi) There are 300 rules in total and 70% has the common similarity. refer to the common rules example below.

Currently i am using easy rules concept and java custom constraint validator to handle this as below and i am exploring more advance option such as rule engine as mentioned above.

- (Easy Rule) https://alvinalexander.com/java/easy-rules-example-java-rules-engine-android-football-game
- (java custom constraint validator) https://www.journaldev.com/3626/hibernate-validator-jsr303-example-tutorial

Given on Json format below with many different kind of rules scenario, should i  consider a rule engine to handle this or java easy  rules and java custom constraint validator able to handle this ?

## Code example and more info as below

## Common rules as below base on the json format as below else error will be thrown

1) "visit.clientId" json field cannot be null if "visit.clientRevision" json field is not null and "visit.clientInfo" json field is not null

2) "visitDetails" json object only can be submitted if "visit" json object is not null

3) "visit.clientId" cannot be null if visitor age is more than 12 years old and "locationCode" is within the range of "10" to "1000"

4) "visit.clientId" value only can be submitted allowed if visitor age is between 12 years old to 21 years old and "locationCode" is "1" and "2"

5) "visitDetails.screeningInfo.height" cannot be null if "visitDetails.screeningInfo" .bmi is given

6) "visit.clientId" value only can be submitted allowed if visitor age is between 21 years old to 100 years old and "locationCode" is "100" or "200"

```
    {

        "refFormId": 3,
        "locationCode": "2",
        "visit": {
            "facilityCode": "2",
            "eventDate": "2017-11-01 15:07:06",
            "refServiceTypeId": 2,
            "clientRevision": 0,
            "clientId": 1,
            "serialNumber": "serial1"
        },
        "visitDetails": {
            "refDetailsID": 3,

            "screeningInfo": {
                "height": 100,
                "weight": 100,
                "bmi": 100,
                "screenLocation": 1,
                "screenLocationOther": "screenLocationOther",


                "healthMorbidityScope": [{
                        "refHealthMorbidifyScopeId": 1,
                        "otherDetails": "other1",
                        "refScopes": [2, 3, 4]
                    },
                    {
                        "refHealthMorbidifyScopeId": 2,
                        "otherDetails": "other2",
                        "refScopes": [1, 2, 3]
                    }
                ]

            }
        }
    }
```

## Example on java custom constraint validator below on the Pojo Class file

## Example Java code 1

Rule requirement - "visitDetails.screeningInfo.height" cannot be null if "visitDetails.screeningInfo.bmi" is given)

If requirement not met for run time json value, then error will be thrown

```
@NotNullIfAnotherFieldHasValue.List({
        @NotNullIfAnotherFieldHasValue(conditionType = dictionary.REF_VALIDATOR_IF_DEPENDENT_FIELD_EQUAL_SOMETHING,    // checking type is whether notNullFieldName can be null
                conditionIfFieldNameA = "bmi", // if bmi given and not null then height is not allowed to be null
                conditionIfSelectedValueA = "dictionary.ANYTHING",
                notNullFieldName = "height", // field to be checked whether allowed to be null
                message = "{domain.constraint.notNullIfAnotherFieldHasValue.scenario1}") })
```

## Example java code 2

Rule requirement - visit.clientId value only can be submitted allowed if visitor age is between 12 years old to 21 years old and "locationCode" is "1" and "2"

If requirement not met for run time json value, then error will be thrown

```
@AgeValidator.List({
        @AgeValidator(
                allowedFieldName = "clientId",     // checking for clientId
                conditionIfFieldName = "locationCode",   // locationCode must be range 1 and 2 as conditionIfSelectedValue
                conditionIfSelectedValue = [1,2],    
                checkingType = dictionary.REF_VALIDATOR_FIELD_IS_ALLOWED,   // checking type is whether value can be submitted
                allowedPatientAge = "12", allowedPatientAgeUpto = "21",   // age must be between 12 to 21 
                conditionType = LookupConstants.REF_AGE_IN_BETWEEN)     
        })
```